# How to test a Python script with an input file filled with testcases?

Tags: python, input

I'm participating in online judge contests and I want to test my code with a .in file full of testcases to time my algorithm. How can I get my script to take input from this .in file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the script normally takes test cases from stdin, and now you want to test using test cases from a file?

If that is the case, use the `<` redirection operation on the cmd line:

```
my_script < testcases.in
```

Answer (score 2):

Read from file(s) and/or stdin:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

[PyUnit](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/) "the standard unit testing framework for Python" might be what you are looking for.

---

Doing a small script that does something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

def main():
    in_file = open('path_to_file')
    for line in in_file:
        sys.stdout.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And run as

```
this_script.py | your_app.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a separate file.

`testmyscript.py`

```
import sys
someFile= open( "somefile.in", "r" )
sys.stdin= someFile
execfile( "yourscript.py" )
```